# Why can't I deploy my flow?

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow

Here's my error:

> SA_Request_Notification (Action) - We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified.

Here's the name of the file being deployed:

> flows/Account_Request_Service_Agreement.flow-meta.xml

Here's some of the metadata from said flow file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <actionCalls>
        <name>SA_Request_Notification</name>
        <label>SA Request Notification</label>
        <locationX>1645</locationX>
        <locationY>490</locationY>
        <actionName>Contract.Contract_Service_Agreement_Request_Notification</actionName>
        <actionType>emailAlert</actionType>
        <faultConnector>
            <targetReference>Set_Error_0</targetReference>
        </faultConnector>
        <inputParameters>
            <name>SObjectRowId</name>
            <value>
                <elementReference>contractId</elementReference>
            </value>
        </inputParameters>
    </actionCalls>
```

Seems to me the very first section of the flow (pasted above) contains an action with the desired name

Answer (score 1):

After some more trial and error, I believe the `<actionName>` element in my original post, contains the value throwing the actual error. Namely:

> Contract.Contract_Service_Agreement_Request_Notification

is referring to an alert defined within a `Contract.workflow-meta.xml` file in my `workflows` directory which contains an alert by this name

```xml
    <alerts>
        <fullName>Contract_Service_Agreement_Request_Notification</fullName>
    ...etc
```